Fill Missing Values in a datetime64[ns] col - pandas
If I have a df like this one:
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'A': range(6),
        'D': pd.date_range('20240101', periods = 6, freq = 'D')
    }
)

df['D'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
df.loc[2 , 'D'] = pd.NaT

How to fill the missing value in the column 'D' using:
.interpolate(method = 'time') please?

Should the interpolated values in D depend on that of A?

No, thanks for you answer below :-)

You were almost there:
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'A': range(6),
        'D': pd.date_range('20240101', periods = 6, freq = 'D')
    }
)
df['D'] = df['D'].astype('int64') ## give time in ns 
df.loc[2 , 'D'] = np.nan

df['D'] = df['D'].interpolate()
df['D'] = df['D'].astype('datetime64[ns]')  # back to timestamp
display(df)

    A   D
0   0   2024-01-01
1   1   2024-01-02
2   2   2024-01-03
3   3   2024-01-04
4   4   2024-01-05
5   5   2024-01-06


Just interpolate, it will work out of the box. method='time' would make sense if your dates were the index and you wanted to interpolate values based on the dates.
df['D'] = df['D'].interpolate()

Output:
   A          D
0  0 2024-01-01
1  1 2024-01-02
2  2 2024-01-03
3  3 2024-01-04
4  4 2024-01-05
5  5 2024-01-06

If you want to interpolate based on the values in A, this is indeed not yet supported for datetime dtypes, and you temporalily need to use integers:
s = df.set_index('A')['D']
df['D_interp'] = pd.to_datetime(s.astype(int)
                                 .where(s.notna())
                                 .interpolate('values')
                                ).values

Output (changing 2 to 2.5 for the demo):
     A          D            D_interp
0  0.0 2024-01-01 2024-01-01 00:00:00
1  1.0 2024-01-02 2024-01-02 00:00:00
2  2.5        NaT 2024-01-03 12:00:00
3  3.0 2024-01-04 2024-01-04 00:00:00
4  4.0 2024-01-05 2024-01-05 00:00:00
5  5.0 2024-01-06 2024-01-06 00:00:00

